# map function concludes after one successful execution

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, map-function

I am trying to map an array and fetch relevant data from MySQL and then again map the array returned by MySQL and send tweets. With this logic, the app only sends tweet for one element in the array.  But, it actually needs to send multiple tweets as it maps through the array.
Here is the code:

```
array.items.map(item => {
  con.query(`SELECT username FROM users where country="${item.country}"`, async function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);

    result.length > 0 && result.map(async user => {
      try {
        await sendTweet(`Hello ${user.username}, your selected country is ${item.country}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.body)
        return false
      }
    })
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'd appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: You should use `.forEach()` for this, not `.map()`

Comment: hi @StudioTime I used `forEach()` instead of the two map function, but the same issue still persists.

Comment: Can you show what the log of `result` is?

Comment: result: `[ { username: '@abcde' } ]` this is the result of one query, but the item has to repeat more times and return more result.

Comment: But you said: `because the results contain more than one element` which is not the case, it seems it's behaving correctly

Comment: yes, but multiple results are returned for different items in the array, yet the tweet is only sent for one item/result.

Comment: @StudioTime I edited the question. The above logic concludes after sending tweets for one item (even though multiple tweets). What is the reason for this?

Comment: What's in `array`? Change both `.map()` to `.forEach()`

Comment: Yes, I did that already, but the issue still persists.

Comment: maybe it is due to the way mysql query works?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no need to async and await.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.map(item => {

  // con.query
  setTimeout(function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    result = [11, 22, 33];

    result.length > 0 && result.map(user => {
      try {

        // sendTweet
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(`Hello ${user.username}, your selected country is ${item.country}`);
        }, 500);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return false
      }
    })
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: how does setTimeout affect this code?

Comment: It demonstrates asynchronous call (since I can't query the db). You should just remove all the `await` and `async` from yours.

Comment: do I need to use setTimeout?

Comment: No. You should just remove all the `await` and `async` from your function. Sorry for confusion but I couldn't execute your code as is.

Comment: for the sendTweet code, the documentation suggests using await.

Comment: why do you think async/await is the reason for the above issue?

Comment: I'm note sure it's the reason, but they are not needed. I didn't test it.

Comment: ok, the above logic only sends tweets to one item. After that, it is not sent. What might be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the function `Promise.all`

```
if (result.length) {
  try {
      await Promise.all(result.map(user => {
          return sendTweet(`Hello ${user.username}, your selected country is ${item.country}`);
      }));
  } catch(e) {
      //Handle the error
  }
}
```

Comment: this still sends only one tweet

Comment: I think the error is in the array.items.map. Becaue I can send multiple tweets per one item. But after that it is not sending any tweet to other items.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would maybe write it.

IMO we don't need to await for sendTweet

If you expect some field to be undefined, it is possible to assign a default value through [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), see `username` below

```
async function tweetAll(item, error, users) {
  if(error) {
    console.log('error', error.message)
  }
  else {
    for(const user of users) {
      sendTweet(`Hello ${user?.username ?? 'User'}, your selected country is ${item.country}`)
    }
  }
}

for(const item of array.items){
  con.query(`SELECT username FROM users where country="${item.country}"`, (error, users) => tweetAll(item, error, users))
}
```

Comment: How does the tweetAll function recognize item?

Comment: eventhough I executed this code removing item, the code only executes for one item. I only receive one tweet.

Comment: Actually I need to pass item inside the tweetall function, because I need more details about each item, is there a way?

Comment: when I use this, it throws 403 error, possible twitter client api. When I remove the await keyword, the code works but no tweet sent.

Comment: hey your for loop is correct? because for me it throws error like undefined.

Comment: yes, for some items, there is no data on the db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246162/discussion-between-giulp-and-nithur).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of MySQL with node.js much but here's what I'm understanding from your code.

```
array.items.map(user => {
  do something async; 
});
```

Issue with this is it'll only run the async process once because loop won't wait for it to complete.

Insteas try this

```
array.items.forEach(async user => {
await 'do something async'
});
```

So you need to wait for your async process to complete. Not sure if MySQL supports await but you can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for doing so.

EDIT:
If your purpose is simply to fetch data for multiple where conditions, here's my suggestion

Turn your loop-> where query to a single WHERE IN query.

```
str = '(';
arr.map(item => {
  str += item.toString();
}

str += ')';

conn.query(`SELECT * from table WHERE country IN ${str}`)
```

Let me know if that works
[Check here SQL IN query](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Comment: what if I try to fetch all data from MySQL and then iterate through the results and do the remaining work?

Comment: @Nithur You can do that but keep in mind that if there's a lot of data, it'll consume memory and your application might get slow for the time being.
I've a better suggestion, change your query to a WHERE IN query